# Let $I$ be a non null ideal in $A$ P.I.D, if $A/I$ is an integer domain it is also a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I have no work to show. This fact is presented in my book as an obvious corollary of the following theorem:

**Theorem:**

If I=$(p)$ is an non null ideal in A P.I.D, $I$ is prime iff it is maximal.

Thanks in advance, every help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what is the relationship between prime ideals, maximal ideals, fields, and integral domains?

Comment: @MarkSaving A/I is a field iff I is maximal in an integral domain, and so iff I is prime in a P.I.D